# Not all finite exchangeable families can be infinitely extended

Tags: probability-theory

> Give an example of a finite exchangeable family $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ which can not be extended to an infinite exchangeable family $X_1, X_2, \ldots$.

Luckily, such a counterexample can be found in the book "Counterexamples in Probability" by J. M. Stoyanov.

But I don't understand it... here it is

---

[image]

---

Why does the second last row read:
$$\frac{1}{2} n + \sum_{j\neq k} \mathbf{P}[X_j = 0, X_k = 1] - \frac{1}{4} n^2$$
and not
$$\frac{1}{2} n + \sum_{j\neq k} \mathbf{P}[X_j = 1, X_k = 1] - \frac{1}{4} n^2 \quad {\large?}$$

Comment: This follows directly from [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234720).

Comment: @Did: So is the second line of the quoted text correct or not? I also think that the example given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234653) would be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a misprint.  It's ${\bf P}[X_j=1,X_k=1]$ that is $0.2$.